# JQGrid cellEdit doesn't allow rows to get selected

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am trying to implement cellEdit feature for few columns in my JQGrid which happens perfectly using this
`'cellEdit': true, 'cellsubmit': 'remote',`
EditUrl I am setting dynamically.

But when I use these lines in my code, I am unable to select the row on clicking the cell. I am using 
`multiselect: true, multiboxonly: true,`

this is breaking my code. Please help. How can I get cellEdit and row selection both.

Comment: so frankly speaking you want to edit multiple rows?

Comment: no. I want to edit one row at a time using inline editing.
We are trying to achieve something else with multiselect feature

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you can't use `multiselect: true` together cell editing. It you do need that you will have to use `beforeSelectRow` callback to fix the problem.

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/multiselectWithCellEditing.htm) demonstrates the solution. It uses the following implementation of `beforeSelectRow`:

```
beforeSelectRow: function (rowid, e) {
    var $self = $(this), iCol, cm,
        $td = $(e.target).closest("tr.jqgrow>td"),
        $tr = $td.closest("tr.jqgrow"),
        p = $self.jqGrid("getGridParam");

    if ($(e.target).is("input[type=checkbox]") && $td.length > 0) {
       iCol = $.jgrid.getCellIndex($td[0]);
       cm = p.colModel[iCol];
       if (cm != null && cm.name === "cb") {
           // multiselect checkbox is clicked
           $self.jqGrid("setSelection", $tr.attr("id"), true ,e);
       }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Oleg sorry for not replying for so long as I got busy with something else. I tried this code today but it doesn't seems to be achieving what i desire. I was trying to do some modifications to it, but that is breaking. Will post the code here and let me know if you can help me fix it.

Comment: @eranjali08: You should be exact what problem exists. You wrote "I tried this code today but it doesn't seems to be achieving what i desire". It gives no information about the problem which you have. Do you tried [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/multiselectWithCellEditing.htm)? I don't think that click on another column should be interpreted as reset of existing selection because you use cell editing additionally. In any way I don't want to make all your job and implement requirements which you have. I wanted to show you the way how `multiselect` can be implemented with cell edit.

Comment: I went through the demo. The only concern I have with it is that when we click on any cell, the row is selected in the background but it is not showing in the usual 'Yellow' color but is highlighted in blue. Also, the checkbox is not checked.
Is this how it is supposed to work?
I am sorry if my questions sound stupid but I am pretty new to jqGrid :(

Comment: @eranjali08: Sorry, but I can't follow you. You wrote "the checkbox is not checked". Which checkbox you mean (from which column)? Just examine the standard cell editing behavior on [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/multiselectWithCellEditing-onlyCellEditing.htm) and the standard multiselect with `multiboxonly: true` [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/multiselectWithCellEditing-onlyMultiselect.htm). I combined both in once in my demo. To have more common case in the demo I used tree columns (`Client`, `Notes` and `Total`) which I makes as not editable.

Comment: @eranjali08: If a problem exist in my demo, could you describe the exact test case to reproduce the problem? Please describe all steps exactly and add expected results and the results which you see.

Comment: Sorry for all the confusion @Oleg.
I ran your demo and clicked on a cell(other than the one having checkbox which appears by default because of multiselect: true), also ensured that the row is not already selected using multiselect(the row which does not have the multiselect checkbox checked).
Now when I click this cell in a non-selected row(I hope you will get what I mean), I was hoping that multiselect and cellEdit both with work. But that doesn't happens.
I am not sure if this is making any sense :(

Comment: @eranjali08: The standard behavior of cell editing you can see on [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/multiselectWithCellEditing-onlyCellEditing.htm). If the user clicks on a cell then it will be making in editing state (if the column has `editable: true` property) or **the cell will be selected** (if the column has default `editable: false` property). So *no row selection* will be done to implement selections of cells. In general cell editing supports many [callbacks](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:cell_editing#events) which can be used for *additional* actions.

Comment: @eranjali08: By the way the error in the code which you posted exist because you use wrong case in `$self.jqgrid('resetSelection');`. It should be `$self.jqGrid('resetSelection');`. In general you can implement *any behavior of selection* which you want. You need just return `false` from `beforeSelectRow` to prevent standard selection and to use any your custom code inside of `beforeSelectRow` or [cell editing callbacks](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:cell_editing#events).

Comment: @eranjali08: It seems there is a bug in jqGrid 4.7. After [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.7.0/js/grid.base.js#L2790) it need be inserted `return;`. You can try [the fixed version](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.7.0/js/jquery.jqGrid.src-multiselect-and-cellEdit.js) of `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` **without** any additional `beforeSelectRow` callback and compare with the behavior of jqGrid 4.6.

Comment: thanks for pointing out the error. Such a silly mistake. The  **beforeSelectRow** is working fine now. But why did **cellEdit** stop working :-( 
Also, which like are you pointing out in your code above?

Answer (score 0):

Pasting original solution from Oleg's comment:

Edit jquery.jqGrid.src.js and just add return;

```
        if(ts.p.cellEdit === true) {
            if(ts.p.multiselect && scb && cSel){
                $(ts).jqGrid("setSelection", ri ,true,e);
            } else if (td.length > 0) {
                ri = ptr[0].rowIndex;
                try {$(ts).jqGrid("editCell",ri,ci,true);} catch (_) {}
            }
            return; // <---------------------------------------
        }
```